# How to update certain line in text file?

Tags: java, swing, text-files

I have text files patients.txt with information about users.
Which looks like:

```
Name|Lastname|1712995|Female|Adress 1a|555333|username|pass123|Patient|1001|15.06.2019.|1
Name|Lastname|1712995|Female|Adress 3|555333|userpat1|pass123|Patient|1001|15.06.2019.|1
Name|Lastname|1712995|Male|Adress 2nd Street|555333|userpat|pass123|Patient|1001|15.06.2019.|1
```

I created `CreateEditPatientWindow` which is open with empty or with populated fields, depends of what button (create or update) user clicked.

So, if I want to create new patient I create method to write new user in file, like:

```
private void initActions() {
        btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    File patientTextFile = new File("src/txt/patients");
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(patientTextFile, true);
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    PrintWriter pritntWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter, true);
                    pritntWriter.println(txtName.getText() + "|" + txtLastname.getText() + "|" + txtUMCN.getText() + "|"
                            + cbGender.getSelectedItem() + "|" + txtAdress.getText() + "|" + txtPhoneNumber.getText()
                            + "|" + txtUsername.getText() + "|" + txtPassword.getText() + "|" + "Patient" + "|"
                            + txtHealthInsuranceNumber.getText() + "|" + txtExpiryDate.getText() + "|"
                            + cbInsuranceCategory.getSelectedItem());
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException g) {
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So, createing wirks fine.

My question is how to update certain line of text file according username? (usernames will be uniqe)

Here is what I want to achive:

```
private void initActions() {
        btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {

                    File patientTextFileR = new File("src/txt/patients");
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(patientTextFileR);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                    /* PSEUDO CODE for edit
                    if(patientTextFileR containt txtName.getText())
                    {
                        update entire line with values from textfields
                        write the rest of the file
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    //CODE FOR creating new user
                    File patientTextFileW = new File("src/txt/patients");
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(patientTextFileW, true);
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    PrintWriter pritntWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter, true);
                    pritntWriter.println(txtName.getText() + "|" + txtLastname.getText() + "|" + txtUMCN.getText() + "|"
                            + cbGender.getSelectedItem() + "|" + txtAdress.getText() + "|" + txtPhoneNumber.getText()
                            + "|" + txtUsername.getText() + "|" + txtPassword.getText() + "|" + "Patient" + "|"
                            + txtHealthInsuranceNumber.getText() + "|" + txtExpiryDate.getText() + "|"
                            + cbInsuranceCategory.getSelectedItem());   
                    }
                    */

                } catch (IOException g) {
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

`PatientModel.cs` with patient proporties

```
public class PatientModel extends UserModel{

    public int healthInsuranceNumber;
    public String expiryDate;
    public int insuranceCategory;
    public int getHealthInsuranceNumber() {
        return healthInsuranceNumber;
    }
    public void setHealthInsuranceNumber(int healthInsuranceNumber) {
        this.healthInsuranceNumber = healthInsuranceNumber;
    }
    public String getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }
    public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
    public int getInsuranceCategory() {
        return insuranceCategory;
    }
    public void setInsuranceCategory(int insuranceCategory) {
        this.insuranceCategory = insuranceCategory;
    }
    public PatientModel(String name, String lastname, String umcn, String gender, String adress, String phoneNumber,
            String username, String password, String userType, int healthInsuranceNumber, String expiryDate,
            int insuranceCategory) {
        super(name, lastname, umcn, gender, adress, phoneNumber, username, password, userType);
        this.healthInsuranceNumber = healthInsuranceNumber;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        this.insuranceCategory = insuranceCategory;
    }   
}
```

In `UsersClass.cs` i created Arrays like:

```
public ArrayList<PatientModel> patients = getPatients();

public ArrayList<PatientModel> getPatients() {
        ArrayList<PatientModel> patientsList = new ArrayList<PatientModel>();
        try {
            File patientTextFile = new File("src/txt/patients");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patientTextFile));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                String name = split[0];
                String lastname = split[1];
                String umcn = split[2];
                String gender = split[3];
                String adress = split[4];
                String phoneNumber = split[5];
                String username = split[6];
                String password = split[7];
                String userType = split[8];
                int healthInsuranceNumber = Integer.parseInt(split[9]);
                String expiryDate = split[10];
                int insuranceCategory = Integer.parseInt(split[11]);

                PatientModel newPatient = new PatientModel(name, lastname, umcn, gender, adress, phoneNumber, username,
                        password, userType, healthInsuranceNumber, expiryDate, insuranceCategory);
                patientsList.add(newPatient);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return patientsList;
    }

public PatientModel findPatient(String username) {
        for (PatientModel patient : patients) {
            if (patient.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                return patient;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Here is one approach. You need to open the file and traverse it until you find the username. You can then get the contents of the line, modify it and replace it on the file. This is going to be slow though. I'm wondering if it would be possible to use a light weight database like SQLlite. It would make your life so much easier.

Comment: @na-98 Thank's for answer. That is point of my question... how to find username? :)
If you need more code I'll post it.
Surley it would be much easyer using SQlite but this is homeworkproject where I have to use text files.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to update certain line of text file according username?

While finding the line in the file is easy enough. You read each line and check if it starts with the username.

The problem is in saving data. You can't just remove/add characters of data in the middle of the file.

You need to rewrite the entire file. So you would essentially need to read the entire file into an ArrayList. Then search the ArrayList for the line starting with your user name and change the data. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and write out each entry to the file.

Another approach would be to use a `Properties` class. It allows you to store data with key/value pairs. The username would be the key. Then you can update the values for the given key.

However, you still need to save the data. The `Properties` class provides `store(...)` and `load(...)` methods that allow you to do this easily. Note, these methods will still rewrite the entire file and read the entire file when invoked.

This class is essentially a poor man's database.

Comment: Here is what i want to achive but don't know how to write it in java...
Could you, please, help me with this certain example?
I edited question.

Comment: I know what you want to achieve and I gave you two suggestions on how you can do this. Choose an approach and try to implement it. I suspect you should be using the first approach. So where is your code to read all the data in the file into an ArrayList? Forget about your real application and first learn how to read each line of data in a file and display the data. Once you get that working then you add in the ArrayList logic. Once that works then you write the data from the ArrayList. You need to solve the problem one step at a time.

Comment: If you need help with the file I/O then search the forum/web for example that use the BufferedReader class and the readLine() method. These example will almost always show the looping code needed to read the entire file.

Comment: So then you have the basic logic done. You already have logic that finds the Patient (in the ArrayList) you want to change. So you change the data and then you recreate the file with all the Patients found in the ArrayList. Once again, you can't just update a single Patient. The entire file needs to be recreated. So the code in your "Confirm" button, simply iterates through all the Patients in the ArrayList and writes them to the file.

Comment: I tried this way:
`ArrayList<PatientModel> patientsList = usersClass.getPatients();
     String username = txtUsername.getText().trim();
     
     for(PatientModel patientData : patientsList)
     {      
      if (username.equals(patientData.getUsername()))
      {
       System.out.println("FOUND");
       }
      else
      {
       System.out.println("NOT FOUND"); 
      }
     }`
For every line of txt file Console print does username found or not. Works fine, it found correct line. How to rewrite that line?
`content = patientData.getUsername().replace(old, new)`

Comment: *How to rewrite that line?* - why are you talking about "that line"? How many times do I have to tell you that you `can't replace that line in the file`? You need to `rewrite the entire file`. So first you update the data in your Patient class. Then you iterate through all the Patients and write the data for each Patient to the file. What do you find so confusing about that?

Comment: I understand that I have to rewrite the entire file, but you don't  understand what I mean by 'updating/replace' line? 
I readed entire file, okey, and now I want to rewrite entire file with new values.
So, old lines which not changed will write to file again same as the were before rewriting.
 I understand the logic, but how to write that in java? That's confusing. :D

Comment: Why is it confusing? You already know how to write one line to the file. So now you just use a loop. You know how to use a loop to read all the data  one line at a time and create a Patient object that you add to the ArrayListt. This is just the opposite. You use a loop to get each Patient and then write the data to the file.

Comment: @NitrusBrio, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.